# Error al instalar paquetes : "pip" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo

Tags: python, pip

Tengo el *pip* instalado pero al intentar instalar un modulo de Python con la consola con *pip* me sale el siguiente mensaje:

**"pip" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.**

Mi suposición es que hay algun problema con *path* de modo de que no se puede encontrar el *pip*

Disculpen si ya existe una pregunta similar es que soy principiante y no entiendo demasiado

Comment: Si tienes pip instalado, debe estar en alguna parte. ¿Cual es el path donde reside el ejecutable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Las dos causas mas comunes de este error son que no este instalado o que no este agregado al PATH.

### pip no esta instalado

En el caso de Windows pip debe venir incluido en el binario si se descarga del [sitio oficial](https://www.python.org/downloads/) y se usa la instalación por defecto. En Linux generalmente se distribuye como un paquete independiente (que realmente lo es), por lo que hay que instalarlo aparte.

Si pip esta instalado, deberías poder importar el modulo en un script o en el interprete interactivo con `import pip`. También deberías poder usar pip como modulo desde la terminal:

```
python -m pip --version
```

En caso de no tener el paquete instalado, podemos hacer uso de `ensurepip` para instalarlo:

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

`ensurepip` debe venir siempre instalado a no ser que el distribuidor del paquete Python que se use lo eliminara explícitamente. La otra opción es usar el script `get-pip`, para mas información ver la [documentación de pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#supported-methods).

### pip no esta agregado al PATH

Aunque lo tengamos instalado, si no esta agregado al PATH no podremos ejecutarlo desde la terminal a no ser que proporcionemos la ruta al ejecutable. En Windows hay que asegurarse de [marcar la casilla del instalador](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#installation-steps) para que agregue python al PATH.

En este caso deberemos localizar el ejecutable de pip. En el caso de Windows debería estar en el directorio `Scripts` dentro de la carpeta de instalación de Python.

---

### Invocar a pip como modulo

Mi recomendación es que pases directamente de agregarlo al PATH y no uses `pip` como comando nunca, menos en Windows cuando se actualiza el propio paquete `pip` a si mismo. En el sitio son bastante frecuentes los errores debidos a instalar con pip como comando sin saber la versión de Python que tiene asociada y por tanto en el intérprete que instala, errores del tipo "instalo con pip y luego me dice:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modulo_que_no_se_donde_se_instaló' :)
```

**`pip` es un paquete como cualquier otro, la forma más segura y legible de usarlo y de asegurarte de instalar en el intérprete que quieres instalar es ejecutarlo como módulo de la forma:**

```
python -m pip install modulo_a_instalar
```

Dado que usas Windows tendrás **Python Launcher** instalado (se instala por defecto si no desmarcas la casilla del instalador), y quizás es la forma más simple, por lo que puedes hacer:

```
py -m pip install modulo_a_instalar
```

---

```
py -3.7 -m pip install modulo_a_instalar
```

---

```
py -3.8 -m pip install modulo_a_instalar
```

etc, dependiendo de la versión que tengas instalado o en la que quieras instalar de las que tienes.

Si no tienes Python agregado al PATH ([por no haber marcado la casilla](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#installation-steps)) puedes agregarlo manualmente o usar la ruta absoluta al intérprete (python.exe) en el que quieres instalar, algo como:

```
C:\users\usuariox\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-64\python.exe -m pip install modulo_a_instalar
```

Obviamente cambia la ruta por la de tu interprete.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Pude instalar el modulo que queria pero por alguna razon cuando intento 'importarlo' en mi programa me sigue apareciendo como si no existiese. Alguna idea de por que sucede eso?

Comment: ¿Que IDE o editor usas? Como comento en la respuesta pip instala en la versión de Python que uses, si tu editor ejecuta el código en otro intérprete que tengas instalado o en un entorno virtual distinto el módulo no será encontrado. Aparte de ésto asegurate de esar importando bien ¿Qué modulo es y cómo lo importas? Si el error no es un ModulleNotFoundError agrega el error porque la causa puede ser otra.

Comment: Utilizo el Pycharm y si, efectivamente el error es ModulleNotFoundError. El modulo es "inflect" y lo importo con import inflect.

Comment: **EDIT:** finalmente pude instalarlo debido a que el propio Pycharm tiene una opcion para esto. Aun asi me gustaria saber porque no me lo reconocia jaajj

Comment: PyCharm crea un entorno virtual por defecto, usa el mismo intérprete en el que has instalado pero no se comparten los módulos instalados. Los entornos virtuales permiten tener múltiples proyectos con distintos módulos cada uno y distintas versiones instaladas. Por eso preguntaba por el IDE precisamente, sospechaba que PyCharm estaba detrás :). Puedes usar pip también directamente, solo necesitas la ruta al intérprete del entorno virtual (en Pycharm creo que aparece en la misma ventana donde se instalan los paquetes) y hacer como hago en el último ejemplo, o bien activarlo previamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de contestar, voy a tener en cuenta lo que me dijiste.

Answer (score 4):

El problema está en la ubicación del `PATH`.

Primeramente tienes que ver la ruta donde está alojado python.

En la consola de cmd escribe `where python`. Te va a arrojar la ubicación.

Una vez obtenido el directorio, Ve a `Panel de control` > `Sistema y seguridad` > `Sistema`. Has click en `Configuración avanzada del sistema`. Se te abrirá una ventana llamada `Propiedades del sistema`, has click en `Variables de entorno`.
En la parte de abajo, `Variables del sistema`, busca la variable `Path`, la selecciones y le das click en editar.
Cuando se te abra la ventana: `Editar variable de entorno`, has click en `Nuevo`. Ingresas la ubicación o el directorio que te apareció en la consola de cmd: `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\` (ojo: **no** añadas la extensión `python.exe` con el directorio). Y finalmente le das en aceptar, aceptar y aceptar. Reinicias tu computadora y listo.

Answer (score 1):

Para comprobar que pip se ha instalado, ejecuta en la terminal:

pip

Y deberás ver las opciones de uso de la herramienta. Si, en Windows, obtienes "pip" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable, deberás acceder manualmente.

C:\PythonXY\scripts\pip : Donde X e Y corresponden al número de versión de Python

Si todo va bien, ¡has instalado pip correctamente!

Seguido a eso intenta realizar la instalacion asi por ejemplo:
`C:\PythonXY\scripts\pip install django`

Puedes ver mas aca https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/instalacion-y-utilizacion-de-pip-en-windows-linux-y-os-x/

Comment: Al ingrsar en la consola: cd C:\Python3.7\scripts\pip  Me aparece el mensaje: "El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada."

Answer (score 1):

Lo que primero tienes que hacer es instalar el PIP para instalar python con este comando `installing with get-pip.py`, luego instala las librerías que quieras como por ejemplo `pop install django`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más practico, y que me resulto de solución al haber tenido este mismo problema, es desinstalar *Python* y volver a instalar y justo en la ventana de instalación inicial darle check al recuadro de Add Path. De esta forma el aplicativo de instalación agrega de manera automática los Path's para poder acceder desde cualquier lugar del sistema a Python, además, el comando pip será el que esta ligado a la versión que instales, por tanto no será necesario realizar modificaciones y pasos un poco engorrosos!
un saludo

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer].. En tal caso, deberias explicar como hacer eso...

Answer (score 1):

a mi lo que me funcionó, fue simplemente que estaba haciendo referencia a otra versión de python al usar `pip install <modulo>` y estaba totalmente seguro que tenia python instalado. Resulta que fue solamente que no hacia referencia a python 3.x `pip3 install <modulo>` al igual que tratar de ejecutar un script, usar `python3 <archivo>.py`

Comment: El error `pip no se reconoce como comando ...` se debe a que no de ha agregado al path, tu solución fallaría de todas formas ya que `pip` sigue sin estar en el path

Comment: @Christian Sii estaba agregado, y me costo un examen en la universidad no usar pip3 desde un inicio

Comment: En tu caso si, pero en el de la pregunta nop. Por eso digo que tu solución fallaría para el autor de la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

quiero poner esta alternativa porque hice todo lo de arriba y no funcionaba hasta que desinstale python y ademas visual studio code, sólo asi se desinstala correctamente y ya al instalarlo de nuevo poniendo la opcion add path no tuve problemas.

Comment: Hola, Camila. En realidad todo este hilo ha quedado obsoleto. pip es un proyecto externo a python, por lo que no viene incluido por defecto en la instalación. Las últimas versiones de python incluye el módulo [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) que asegura la instalación de pip una vez tengas instalado python. No es necesario desinstalar nada, tan sólo seguir las instrucciones (`python -m ensurepip --upgrade`).

Answer (score -2):

primero probé desinstalar python desde su propio instalador, y volviendolo a instalar, acá es importante marcar la casilla en el instalador de agregar al path, a partir de este punto ya pude usar el gestor de paquetes desde el cmd