# No puedo usar pip para instalar matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

estoy tratando de instalar la librería matplotlib para python, seguí los pasos de un tutorial y con la tecla de **`windows + R`** abrí una ventana en la cual escribí cmd, luego lo siguiente:

```
C:\Users\Kevin C>pip install matplotlib
```

el problema es que me dice esto:

> C:\Users\Kevin C>pip install matplotlib "pip" no se reconoce como un
>   comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: No tines `pip` agregado al PATH, pero ni lo agregues, instala con `py -m pip install matplotlib`. si tienes varias versiones de Python instalado especifica la versión `py -3.8 -m pip install matplotlib`. Asumo que tienes Python Launcher instalado, si no desmarcaste la casilla del instalador lo debes tener. Si no (suponiendo que si tienes Python agregado al PATH) usa `python -m pip install matplotlib`

Comment: Posible duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/348101/15089

Comment: Puede ser, porque como has mencionado, con el atajo de teclado `windows + R` lo que haces es abrir una nueva CMD pero no la estás ejecutando como administrador

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba utilizando el siguiente comando

```
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

Seguramente así te funcionará. Para instalar cualquier otra librería, comienza con `python -m pip install` y luego coloca el nombre de la librería que deseas instalar.